# Livevalidation and group of checkbox, radio, select

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

Livevalidation script is great to validate forms but how you 're suppose to do with group of checkbox, radio, and select. see website : http://www.livevalidation.com/

Comment: Can you set already validated data into that radio, checkboxes and select?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, though LiveValidation will fight you.  You can't attach a validator to an input type="radio".

So what I have done is add a dummy input element something like:

```
<input id="foo" type="text" style="display: none;" value="1" />
```

to my form, then add a Validate.Custom to that.  The custom validation function would be something like

```
function () {
    return $('input[name=myRadioName]:checked').length;
}
```

This is what I did using the standalone LiveValidation and jQuery; probably can do something similar with prototype.js if you're using that version.  One gotcha is that you *must* assign a value attribute to your dummy input element, because LiveValidation seems to skip inputs that have no value (excepting of course Validate.Presence).

Answer (score 1):

For a select, you can use it just fine.

```
 <select name="foo" id="foo">
     <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
     <option value="value1">value1</option>
     <option value="value2">value2</option>
 </select>
```

But for radio buttons, it doesn't seem to work.

```
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="2" />
```

LiveValidation only works for elements that have an "id", which is not possible with radio buttons. Seems like a limitation of LiveValidation. Anyone has a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and came up with another way to look at it. I was using my radio group for acesses level -

- Level one
- Level two

So I just added a third level and set it to selected so that field is in essence required with a dummy value if you don't address the field.

- Level one
- Level two
- no access