# LiveValidation JavaScript library - radio buttons

Tags: javascript, livevalidation

Any leads or articles which showcase validating radio buttons using LiveValidation JavaScript library?

Use case - validation that on click of Submit button of the form, radio buttons have an option selected.

Referred the article [LiveValidation JavaScript library](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/using-livevalidation-javascript-library) but it nowhere states usage for Radio button validation.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you generating radio buttons on runtime. What kind of validation do you want to put

Comment: @Stakshi updated the question. Please let me know if there is any way to do it with LiveValidation Javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5: How to use the "required" attribute with a "radio" input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field)

Comment: sorry but I don't want to go with required attribute but by the LiveValidation Library as mentioned above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366935/livevalidation-and-group-of-checkbox-radio-select ... please look at more questions related to radio button and LiveValidation